# Using native HTTPS request to patch data in Node.js

Tags: node.js, https, request, patch

I am doing an assignment for https request in Node.js. The assignment requests that using the native https module for patching data. Also, the data we want to update can be input after the js file, like node xxx.js "update something". The question is when patching, the update is uploaded but the old data is not updated. So, it causes that the new and old data exist together. Thanks!

```
const https = require('https');

const args = process.argv;
const act = args[2];
const update = args[3]

const options = {
    hostname: 'reqres.in',
    port: 443,
    path: `/api/users/${act}`,
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}

const req = https.request(options.options_patch, res => {
    let data = '';
    console.log('Status: ', res.statusCode)
    console.log('Headers: ', JSON.stringify(res.headers))
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', chunk => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Body: ', JSON.parse(data));
    })
  }).on('error', e => {
    console.error(e);
  })

  req.write(JSON.stringify(update));
  req.end();
}
```

Comment: And the problem is ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const https = require('https');

const args = process.argv;
const act = args[2];
const update = args[3];

const options = {
    hostname: 'reqres.in',
    port: 443,
    path: `/api/users/${act}`,
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {

    let data = '';

    console.log('Status: ', res.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers: ', JSON.stringify(res.headers));

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Body: ', JSON.parse(data));
    });

}).on('error', e => {
    console.error(e);
});

req.write(update);
req.end();
```

`node test.js path "data"`

> Status:  200
> Headers:  {"date":"Wed, 08 Jul 2020 12:59:16 GMT","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","content-length":"50","connection":"close","set-cookie":["__cfduid=d76ab451f50acf77b2fe9da83cbff44521594213156; expires=Fri, 07-Aug-20 12:59:16 GMT; path=/; domain=.reqres.in; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure"],"x-powered-by":"Express","access-control-allow-origin":"*","etag":"W/"32-PB4zlwTjg/gFA9Skv/cu8Rzo1N4"","via":"1.1 vegur","cf-cache-status":"DYNAMIC","cf-request-id":"03d01b5e6500000c1117955200000001","expect-ct":"max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"","server":"cloudflare","cf-ray":"5af9fb43d9af0c11-AMS"}
> Body:  { data: '', updatedAt: '2020-07-08T12:59:16.501Z' }

FYI: This could also be done with `curl` or `wget`.

Comment: I tried to put the update in req.write(), but the old information is not updated but the new data can be added after the old one. For example: {old: "old data", "new"}

Comment: @Amy im not sure what you talking about. my code just does a http request, method: "patch", with the payload you add as 3rd argument.